# AdWhirlLayout problem

Tags: android, layout, adwhirl

I have this in my **main.xml**

```
<com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout
    android:id="@+id/timer_ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

And it always results in

**Binary XML file line #117: Error inflating class com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout**

and another interesting line says, 
**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: AdWhirlLayout(Context,AttributeSet)**

Does it mean that I can't use the AdWhirlLayout from the xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. Please check [this](http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/issues/detail?id=95&q=adwhirl%20layout&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Stars%20Status%20Priority%20Opened%20Summary). Thank you @Viktor Bresan for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about it,but refer the below url's,it may help you 
http://malsandroid.blogspot.com/2010/05/admob-and-adwhirl.html
http://www.adwhirl.com/pdf/AdWhirl_OpenSourceSDK_Setup_Instructions-Android.pdf

Comment: hi..dude please try this sample http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html