# Add Adwhirl in Dialog causes Inflate Exception

Tags: android, adwhirl

i get an Inflate Exception,
**android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class**,
while adding AdWhirl Layout in the XML and set this XML as Content-View of the Dialog, i don't know why this exception is occurring and how to resolve it please guide me to solve this issue, i think following code will help u to diagnose that where problem resides:

This is my XML, where i have added Adwhirl layout:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="250dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        >

        <com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout <!-- Exception occurred on this line--> 
                android:id="@+id/adwhirl_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />                 
        </LinearLayout>
```

And in the Java Code:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
    @Override   

     public void run() {

        isShowed = true;
        dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext()); 

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.replay_screen);//Exception occurred on this line   

    }
    });
```

Comment: check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975989/adwhirllayout-problem

Comment: OK i have resolved this issue as now i am adding Adwhirl view through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue as now i am adding AdWhirl View by Code.